# What determines the "best" class/role for each unit?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

I am still in the early parts the game and unlocking more and more combat techniques and character customization as I go. Despite everything I have learned so far, one thing I am having a hard time wrapping my head around is how certain units "excel" as certain roles/classes. Each unit starts off with their own unique class, which fills the typically fighter/healer/tank role in an RPG.

Initially, it makes sense to leave each unit as their starting class until it is rank 10, and then the game encourages you to try out different classes once you've reached that soft-cap. The game itself does not guide you down a specific path on which unit functions better as which class. However, there are many guides out there that give their suggestions on which class certain units perform better as than others.

What actually determines the "best" class/role for each unit? As far as I can tell, each unit will get the same arts for each class, so are there other hidden mechanics that would derive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each character has a rank of how well that character matches that class.  Usually this has to do with story or personality things, as opposed to, for example, Lanz always being good at tanking.  You can tell how good a character is at a specific class by looking at the top right corner of the class in the class menu.  For example, below is a picture of Noah looking at the Swordfighter class (his default one).  You'll note he's S ranked for it.

For the same class, other characters will have different rankings there.  In general, try to pick class/character combinations that are highly ranked, and you'll be a bit better off.

As a bonus, the other ratings are:

Sword: Class Attacker rating

Shield: Class Defender rating

Heart: Class Healer rating

Rook: Difficulty of player class control (A is easier - the swordfighter is quite easy to control)

[image: Partial screenshot of class selection, showing a winged S in the top right corner]

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your answer. I remember the tutorial going over the Sword/Shield/Heart/Rook ratings, but I guess I completely overlooked the ranking on the top-right

Comment: I'm not too convinced about this answer. The in-game tip about the class affinity only mention that the affinity rank influence the amount of CP gained by a character with said class. So I went to check, I assigned the Guardian Commander (Zeon) class to Mio and Lanz, both have a B rank in affinity with it and were rank 10. I removed all gems, accessories and master skills. Both were at level 62, yet Lanz had around 5700HP while Mio had 4980HP, and Mio had more Dexterity and Agility than Lanz (which relate to Lanz starting with a beefy tank while Mio was a dodge tank).